# Updating my own nuget server results in "A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm running a Nuget server in version 2.7 and I wanted to update it to the latest version available.

The update is working fine. But when I try to run the updated version, I get this error :

### Server Error in '/EM-Nugets-Alpha' Application.

A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added.
Parameter name: virtualPath 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added.
Parameter name: virtualPath

Source Error:

```
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[ArgumentException: A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added.
Parameter name: virtualPath]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRouteHandler.AddServiceInfo(String virtualPath, ServiceDeploymentInfo serviceInfo) +120399
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRoute..ctor(String routePrefix, ServiceHostFactoryBase serviceHostFactory, Type serviceType) +67
   NuGetServer.NuGetRoutes.MapRoutes(RouteCollection routes) +96

[HttpException (0x80004005): A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added.
Parameter name: virtualPath]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12949749
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): A route with the resolved virtual path '~/nuget' has already been added.
Parameter name: virtualPath]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12966756
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12806561
```

I'm not enough familiar with this type of errors, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly found the problem : the name of my project was too close to Nuget.Server

With a name far away from Nuget.Server, the server restart running as it should.